# How to access css file inside a folder in codeigniter application?

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I am creating a web page and trying to access a stylesheet which is inside a "application/css/" folder. So how we can access this file and what helper function should use? Below is the head section I used in php file.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
```

If I use base_url('css/style.css') or link_tag('css/style.css'), it is returning url like 'http://localhost/test/css/style.css' which does not return path of css file.'http://localhost/test' is the base url.

Comment: try href="/app/css/style.css"

Comment: Hi, the css files should be out of the application folder. so that you can use the base url function to call the css files.

Comment: It can be like css/style.css in the root/under your project folder. then only it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **Not Recommended** that you have css or images in applications folder

Create a assets folder in main directory

```
application
assets
assets > css
assets > images
assets > js
system
index.php
```

On view use example `<?php echo base_url('assets/css/stylesheet.css');?>`

Autoload the url helper also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>" />
</head>
```