# css and js files have 403 forbidden error after activating mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm working on an application using Codeigniter Framework . 
I wanted to remove the index.php from the url , so I activated the mod_rewrite , and I modified the .htacces files , the index.php has been removed , and the application run perfectly but the css files and and js files dont want to load .

to loads a css file i use this line

```
<link <?php echo 'href="' . base_url() . 'application/views' . '/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"' ?>>
```

but it says

```
You don't have permission to access /kingplast/application/views/css/bootstrap.min.css on this server.
```

for more informations i'll provide my 000-default.conf file and the .htacces file

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>




# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

.htacces

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /kingplast/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and by the way i tried to chmod the files to 777 and it didn't worked .
for more information i'm running Ubuntu 15.04

please help me i'm stacked

Comment: You cannot access css and js through application folder create a assets folder in main directory best option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410940/how-to-access-css-file-inside-a-folder-in-codeigniter-application/30411007#30411007

Comment: i can access css and js from application folder , actually it was working

Comment: Not Not Recommended Though I Been Told

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this and try again:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```